# Reload the whole app when routing back to my home page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How do I reload the whole app when routing back to my home page in Angular.
I have setup the routes like this.

```
Routes = [
{path: 'member-dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./member-dashboard/member- 
dashboard.module').then(m => m.MemberDashboardModule), canActivate: [DashboardGuard]},
{path: '' , component: IndexComponent},
{path: 'sign-in' , component: SignInComponent},
{path: 'abouts' , component: AboutsComponent},
{path: 'artists' , component: ArtistsComponent},
{path: 'contacts' , component: ContactsComponent}
];
```

Comment: Do you use button or method(routing-programmatically) for this?

Comment: i use buttons for in-app navigation

Comment: Then use <a href="/" type="button" class="btn_classes"></a> tag for achiev this simply. Use href for link to home page route.

Comment: is there a way to do it in the router file itself